# Maximum of some specific columns in a spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this.

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  M| c2| c3| d1|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|2_1|4_3|1_2|
|  2|3_4|4_5|1_2|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I have to transform this df should look like below. Here, `c_max = max(c2,c3)` after splitting with `_`.ie, all the columns (`c2` and `c3`) have to be splitted with `_` and then getting the max.

In the actual scenario, I have 50 columns ie, `c2,c3....c50` and need to take the max from this.

```
+---+---+---+---+------+
|  M| c2| c3| d1|c_Max |
+---+---+---+---+------+
|  1|2_1|4_3|1_2|  4   |
|  2|3_4|4_5|1_2|  5   |
+---+---+---+---+------+
```

Comment: did you make any attempt so far?

Comment: I am able to pick the required columns using var cols =Seq("c2","c3")
df1.select(cols.head,cols.tail: _*) .  I am trying this but since I am new to scala getting stuck.

Comment: Also this seems to be little  tricky to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spark >= 2.4.0, you can use the `array_max` function and get some code that would work even with columns containing more than 2 values. The idea is to start by concatenating all the columns (`concat` column). For that, I use `concat_ws` on an array of all the columns I want to concat, that I obtain with `array(cols.map(col) :_*)`. Then I split the resulting string to get a big array of strings containing all the values of all the columns. I cast it to an array of ints and I call `array_max` on it.

```scala
val cols = (2 to 50).map("c"+_)

val result = df
    .withColumn("concat", concat_ws("_", array(cols.map(col) :_*)))
    .withColumn("array_of_ints", split('concat, "_").cast(ArrayType(IntegerType)))
    .withColumn("c_max", array_max('array_of_ints))
    .drop("concat", "array_of_ints")
```

In spark < 2.4, you can define array_max yourself like this:

```scala
val array_max = udf((s : Seq[Int]) => s.max)
```

The previous code does not need to be modified. Note however that UDFs can be slower than predefined spark SQL functions.

Comment: just be aware that this is string based sorting for an array of ["1", "2", "03"] max will be 2

Comment: i am using an older version and array_max is not available it seems.

Comment: @alex, nice catch ;) I modified the code so that it works as expected.

Comment: @abc_spark, I added a way to make it work in earlier versions of spark. I tested with in spark 2.2

Comment: @Oli Thanks for that, but can you please explain the line - concat_ws("_", array(cols.map(col) :_*)))

Comment: I added more details in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way using `expr` and build-in array functions for Spark >= 2.4.0:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, array_max, array}

val df = Seq(
  (1, "2_1", "3_4", "1_2"),
  (2, "3_4", "4_5", "1_2")
).toDF("M", "c2", "c3", "d1")

// get max c for each c column 
val c_cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("c")).map{ c =>
  expr(s"array_max(cast(split(${c}, '_') as array<int>))")
}

df.withColumn("max_c", array_max(array(c_cols:_*))).show
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|  M| c2| c3| d1|max_c|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|  1|2_1|3_4|1_2|    4|
|  2|3_4|4_5|1_2|    5|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

For older versions use the next code:

```scala
val c_cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("c")).map{ c =>
  val c_ar = split(col(c), "_").cast("array<int>")
  when(c_ar.getItem(0) > c_ar.getItem(1), c_ar.getItem(0)).otherwise(c_ar.getItem(1))
}

df.withColumn("max_c", greatest(c_cols:_*)).show
```

Comment: i am using an older version and array_max is not available it seems.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: my version is -  2.3.0

Comment: `expr(s"greatest(cast(split(${c}, '_') as array<int>))")` will actually fail as it requires at least 2 arguments.

Comment: df.withColumn("max_c", greatest(c_items:_*)).show // is this c_cols ?

Comment: that was copy paste mistake @abc_spark I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @blackbishop that is valid I thought there is an overload for arrays as well

Answer (score 3):

Use `greatest` function:

```
val df = Seq((1, "2_1", "3_4", "1_2"),(2, "3_4", "4_5", "1_2"),
).toDF("M", "c2", "c3", "d1")

// get all `c` columns and split by `_` to get the values after the underscore
val c_cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("c"))
                       .flatMap{
                           c => Seq(split(col(c), "_").getItem(0).cast("int"), 
                                    split(col(c), "_").getItem(1).cast("int")
                                )
                        } 

// apply greatest func
val c_max = greatest(c_cols: _*)

// add new column
df.withColumn("c_Max", c_max).show()
```

Gives:

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|  M| c2| c3| d1|c_Max|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|  1|2_1|3_4|1_2|    4|
|  2|3_4|4_5|1_2|    5|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: Hi blackbishop, Thanks for that. I have edited my question lil bit.Sorry about that i could have done this initially itself. Actually, I have to get the max of the integers on each side of "_"

Comment: Thanks for that.Let me try with this.

Comment: But do you have some way to incorporate float as well? as per Alexandro's comment, there can be an issue when - sorting for an array of ["1", "2", "03"] max will be 2

Comment: flatMap{ c => Seq(split(col(c), "_"
).getItem(0).cast("Float"), split(col(c), "_").getItem(1).cast("Float")) } This will serve the purpose I guess.. Thanks

Comment: Hi @blackbishop
Would you be able to advise on the question -  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211108/finding-percentile-in-spark-scala-in-dynamic-way